# session does not work to control panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I have problem with session, I have 2  login pages, one for Admin And one for teacher, when user enter his Id and password, the session created for his name, I used this session in Masterpage so I can control with the appearance of some panels showing url to another pages, but unfortunately it doesn't work, I thought to create different master page for Admin and teacher, but this is a bad solution where some pages common between two, anyway this is the code firstly in master page

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 

if (Session["fname"] == "admin")
{
    Panel2.Visible = false;
    Panel1.Visible = true;
    Panel3.Visible = false;
}
else if (Session["fname"] == "Teacher")
{
    Panel1.Visible = false;
    Panel2.Visible = true;
    Panel3.Visible = false;

}
else
{
    Panel1.Visible = false;
    Panel2.Visible = false;
    Panel3.Visible = true;
}
}
```

and in admin login page

```
string s = "Select ID,Name,Password FROM Admin where ID = '" + TextBox1.Text + "'";
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(s, con);
    SqlDataReader dr;
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (dr.HasRows)
    {
        dr.Read();
        string s1 = dr[2].ToString();
        string s2 = TextBox2.Text;
        if (s1 == s2)
        {
            Session["fname"] = "admin";


            Response.Redirect("ManageCourse.aspx", true);
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "msgbox", "alert('Login Successful');", true);
            HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
        }
```

And in teacher login page

```
 string s = "Select ID,Name,Password FROM Teacher where ID = '"+TextBox1.Text+"'";
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(s,con);
        SqlDataReader dr;
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            dr.Read();
            string s1=dr[2].ToString();
            string s2=TextBox2.Text;
            if (s1 == s2)
            {
                Session["fname"] = "Teacher";


                Response.Redirect("AddQ.aspx", false);
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "msgbox", "alert('Login Successful');", true);
                HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
            }
```

and I added in webconfig this line

```
 <sessionState mode="InProc"/>
```

The desired result that only panel their visible set to true appear, but sessions doesn't work and it only go to the last else where panel3 only appear.

Comment: Can you describe the problem and the desired result? Also I feel the need to warn you that a "log in" should be a username **and** password. Your current code is very easy to attack and it would be trivial to dump all the user ID's or even erase the database. I could log into your admin page simply by typing `blah' OR 1 = 1; -- `.

Comment: @RonBeyer thank you for your advise, I will take it into account. I modified my question now

Comment: I should warn you that the `Cache` object is the same for all users! You might want to use `Session`.

Comment: @VDWWD oh sorry, this is this is last changes I made, but firstly I tried session and it doesn't wark

Comment: What is the actual value of `Session["fname"]`? Check that in debug and work backwards from there. Maybe it is `Admin` or `teacher` or nothing at all. If so find out why it is not what you expect it to be.

Comment: for better session management use class file and make use of httpcurrentcontext along with session type variable. Set its value using get set properties.

Comment: @ShadowWalker sorry, I am newbie in c# and programming, what do you mean by using class file ?

Comment: Then I must say first, how to use classes in C#, only after that you can understand my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the content of session to string.
use method ToString()

if (Session["fname"].ToString() == "admin")

else if (Session["fname"].ToString() == "Teacher")